# Why does RecyclerView List values changes when modified from onCLick onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a List in a RecyclerView``. Whenever I change any object value in Onclick inside `OnBindViewHolder` the main list value changes. I want this but I cannot understand why it is taking place.

Does it guarantees that whenever I change object inside onBindViewHolder, it changes main List?

I think it is due to pass by reference or something.

```
public class AttendanceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AttendanceAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<ChildAttendance> data ;


    public AttendanceAdapter(List<ChildAttendance> childList) {

        data=new ArrayList<>(childList);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         ChildAttendance child =  data.get(position);

         ((ViewHolder) holder).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  child.setName("checked");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`child.setName("checked");` changes value in data. I have a large list. Does it always guarantees the main list changes when I change  any object.

Comment: Yup list pas by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a List in a Recyclerview. Whenever I change any object value in
>   Onclick inside OnBindViewHolder the main list value changes.

It's a correct behaviour in Java. It's because [whenever you're passing a value of an object, you're passing a reference to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/4758255). So, whenever you're instantiating the adapter with the following line:

```
List<ChildAttendance> mainData; // assuming there are data here.
...
AttendanceAdapter adapter = new AttendanceAdapter(mainData);
```

Your `AttendanceAdapter.data` is pointing to the same location with `mainData`. In short, `AttendanceAdapter.data` is an alias for `mainData` object.